# Skype interview for Italian consulate

Tags: schengen-visas

This is our first time travelling to Europe/Italy as a tourist. We have submitted all the documents. The Italian Consulate has scheduled a May 23 Skype interview for me and my husband. Our travel date is the 26th of May.

Is there any way to schedule the Skype interview sooner? Is there any way to contact them to request this?

Comment: Of course there are option to contact them (whoever they are). Just read the letter/email you have and there will be contact information.

Comment: Is it [VHS](http://www.vfs-italy.co.in/Delhi/faq.html) which contacted you for the interview? If so, contact it.

Comment: @Dorothy you mean VFS? It's not about video :)

Comment: @GayotFow +1 I did :D at least I got the link right... and maybe it is about video  !!

Answer (score 1):

It's understandable that you are concerned that the interview is so close to your scheduled departure. The way to discuss a schedule change it to make the request directly with the office or service which arranged the interview. If a specific contact is not mentioned included in your interview notification, look at the instruction on what to do if you cannot keep the appointment. Be mindful that requesting an earlier date may be viewed as cancelling, and new interview appointment may be a later date, not earlier.